# Integrating lettuce with TeamCity

Tags: python, testing, continuous-integration, teamcity, lettuce

Is it possible to use lettuce with TeamCity?
I know it is possible with unittest and nose but since lettuce does not use a standard test runner I cannot use the [teamcity python test runner](https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-python).
If I want to keep TeamCity, should I use another BDD testing framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple Command Line build step with command like this `lettuce --with-xunit --xunit-file=test_results.xml`. Thus you'll be able to track passing/failing features.

Comment: Will teamcity be able to parse the results from the XML file?

Comment: What if lettuce does not genereate the JUnit test results correctly? It's a known issue with lettuce that the JUnit XML results is not reliable.

Comment: All CI servers use JUnit results (except to Jenkins which has xUnit plugin for different test reports) for test results determining and exit code for status determining. So, if command `lettuce` returns non-zero status code, the build will be failed. If JUnit results were not correct, you can still look through Build Log to figure out failing places.